# Rails Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5, owl-carousel

So I'm using a theme that has a file called "Custom.js" that loads scripts from other files. The problem is it doesn't seem to be loading this line from owlCarousel:

```
    (function($){
"use strict";
jQuery(document).on('ready', function () {
    /* Header Sticky
    ========================================================*/
    $(window).on('scroll',function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >70){  
            $('.header-sticky').addClass("is-sticky");
        }
        else{
            $('.header-sticky').removeClass("is-sticky");
        }
    });

    // Nav Active Code
    /*==============================================================*/
    if ($.fn.getfundNav) {
        $('#listingNav').getfundNav({
            theme: 'light'
        });
    };



});
        // Home Slides
        $('.home-slides').owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            dots: false,
            navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
            items: 1,
            smartSpeed: 2000,
            animateOut: 'slideOutUp',
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            animateIn: 'fadeInUp',
            autoplay: true,
        });
........
```

If I take that part of the code out and throw it into my index.html.erb file as a script:

```
<script>
$('.home-slides').owlCarousel({
      loop: true,
      nav: true,
      dots: false,
      navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
```

..then it works just fine.

I know that custom.js is loading because I'm getting the error in chrome. I know that owl.carousel.min.js is loading because if I just throw that code on the index.html.erb... it works.

So I'm a bit confused over why it isn't loading when it's in custom.js but it's loading just fine in the index.html.erb.